AWS Lambda timing out on return statement
I'm trying to write a simple lambda function to use as a view for an application that has parquet data living in an S3 bucket.  I'm just trying to test out a simple function here:
import json
import time
t = time.time()
print('This ')

import os
import urllib.parse
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import awswrangler as wr

print('Imports complete: ', time.time() - t)


s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = os.environ['S3_BUCKET']
    try:
        print('wrangling df')
        df = wr.s3.read_parquet(bucket, dataset=True)
        print('df loaded: ',time.time() - t)
        response = df.to_json()
        print('response type: ', type(response))
        print('df to json: ',time.time() - t)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        print('exception caught: ',time.time() - t)
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(bucket))
        raise e

I'm using the managed python layer on us-west-2:
arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:336392948345:layer:AWSSDKPandas-Python312:13

This is the output with a 60s timeout configured:
Test Event Name
(unsaved) test event

Response
{
  "errorType": "Sandbox.Timedout",
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 24b0f94f-a78e-40e4-9573-0e49ac3eeef3 Error: Task timed out after 60.00 seconds"
}

Function Logs
This 
Imports complete:  4.597054481506348
START RequestId: 24b0f94f-a78e-40e4-9573-0e49ac3eeef3 Version: $LATEST
wrangling df
df loaded:  10.094886779785156
response type:  <class 'str'>
df to json:  10.67463231086731
END RequestId: 24b0f94f-a78e-40e4-9573-0e49ac3eeef3
REPORT RequestId: 24b0f94f-a78e-40e4-9573-0e49ac3eeef3  Duration: 60000.00 ms   Billed Duration: 60000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 126 MB Init Duration: 4874.63 ms   Status: timeout

Request ID
24b0f94f-a78e-40e4-9573-0e49ac3

So it looks like the function is just hanging at the return statement when I test it.  Oddly if I replace return response with return 'some text' it returns right after finishing.  Why would a string several kbs long change the return time by 50+ s?

My guess: you're out of memory.

A Dataframe will only process data when output is required. So, it isn't actually doing anything until the return is requested. If you increase the timeout to 5 minutes, is it the same problem?

Make sure your function has the environment variable which you are using here.

Timeout could also be caused by lack of network route to S3. If you attached the Lambda function to a VPC in your account then don't do that (unless you strictly need to do it, in which case ensure a network route from the Lambda function to S3).

@erik258 - exactly right.  I feel like I've done this before...
